# Automatically adding font size and line height in tinymce 5

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce, tinymce-5

Normally when a user does not choose any specific font size and line height in tinymce, tinymce editor will put the text in a p tag without style. Even when

```
'content_style' => 'body { font-size: 10pt; line-height: 1.7; }'
```

has been adjusted.

I want the font size: 10pt and line height: 1.7 to be automatically added to p tag and text span.

Thanks in advance.